# composer.json: change the vendor-dir dynamically through a script

Tags: composer-php

In a project using Composer, shared by many developers and environments, I need to have the **`vendor-dir` config parameter of `composer.json` to be set dynamically**. That is, a script that runs when `composer install/update` is launched, must be able to change the value of this entry:

```
//composer.json

"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "/var/www/html/......",
```

I tried the following:

```
//composer.json

"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": "MyBundle\\Composer\\Hook::setVendorDir",
```

The class `Hook` has this method:

```php
//MyBundle/Composer/Hook.php

public static function setVendorDir(Event $event)
{
    // ... some code set the $vendorDir variable here depending on many thing
    $event->getComposer()->getConfig()->merge([
        'config' => [
            'vendor-dir' => $vendorDir
        ]
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

The result is that the file `autoloader.php` and a `composer` folder are created in the right vendor directory, but all other packages are still installed in the **default vendor directory**!

The `composer` folder I mentioned only contains some PHP files (`ClassLoader.php`, `_autoload\_*.php_`, and `LICENSE`)

Notice: When I change the `vendor-dir` parameter in `composer.json`, it works flawlessly.

**How may I set `vendor-dir` dynamically and have it taken into account for every package installations?**

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. write a batch script (Windows) or bash script (Linux) or even a PHP script which you run **instead** of `composer install`. The script sets the correct `vendor-dir` in the `composer.json` and then runs `composer install` or whatever.

To set vendor dir just run in your script:

```
composer config vendor-dir /your/path/to/your/vendor/dir
```

For more info about `composer config` see the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#config).

Comment: Thank you for answering. However this will not make it for me because *composer.json* is under version control, and because altering the file itself is not what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You could change it back to its original content after `composer install` anyway I see no other solution at the moment.

Comment: Sure i could but messing with composer.json itself is not clean enough (if the process hangs, you stay with the wrong file for example). And, more important, i really need to achieve a clean code that works as Composer is exepcted to work (manipulating the config).

Comment: Just came across this [plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) and remembered your question. Don't know if this works but merging in a second `composer.json` which is not under version control might be an option for you?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you :) Will give it a try in next project!